# How to remove warnings from lastValue in SparkAR

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, spark-ar-studio

In a SparkAR script, I use `star.transform.z.lastValue` to get the actual number. I want to do some math with the numbers, not with ScalarSignals (observable values). Now by doing so, I get lots of warnings:
[image: SparkAR console warnings]

```
This API is deprecated, please update to the newest SDK version. 
Please use pinLastValue() instead to receive a ConstSignal as a replacement for lastValue
```

I don't see what ConstSignal is or how to extract the value from it, since the documentation seems to be lacking:
https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/search/ConstSignal
I tried doing figure out what kind of fields/functions it has with reflection, but reflection doesn't seem to work in SparkAR, and I don't have code completion on it either. So I have no idea how to resolve this.
Everything works fine when I'm just using `lastValue`, but I'd love to have a clean console.

Note: I am using Spark AR Studio v96

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `star.transform.z.pinLastValue()` to instead.

Comment: I want to use the actual number, not the signal.

Comment: I figured that it actually does return the value, and this mystery ConstSignal doesn't mean anything.